# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Files - Dynamic Load URI with dynamic domain

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been trying to implement functionality in my custom B2C policy files as mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#dynamic-page-content-uri

For wider context, I am nearing the 200 custom B2C policy files limit and as such am trying to reduce my total by merging some near-identical files together. I have 4-5 policy files that are identical save for the value of the `<LoadURI>` tags in the `ContentDefinitions` section.

The issue is the nature of my different/dynamic Load URIs. They all start with `https://`, they all have a `.co.uk` and they all end in `.html`, but otherwise no part of any URI is identical with every other URI. Thus giving B2C the most certain information I can I would need to do something like:

`<LoadUri>https://{OAUTH-KV:LoadUriBase}.co.uk/{OAUTH-KV:LoadUriResource}.html</LoadUri>`

However, I am finding that putting a variable anywhere before the `.co.uk` is resulting in the error 'the hostname could not be parsed' whenever I try to upload the file, and I have been unable to find a way around this issue.

I have thought about setting up a proxy server that dynamically redirects requests to the appropriate domain and just having the B2C policy point to the proxy server but of course it would be a lot simpler to configure the B2C policy file correctly to handle this, if it is possible.

What I have tried (I would post examples but that many URLs triggers StackOverflow's spam filters, so I can't):

I first tried without the `https://` or `.co.uk` parts and just had 2 variables separated by a slash, this of course didn't work and I slowly added parts to construct the above URI.
Since then, I have tried escaping some and all of the `{`, `}` and `:` characters.
I have tried adding spaces in certain places.
I have tried wrapping the whole URI in a CDATA.
I have tried URL-encoding the `{`, `}` and `:` characters.

These all resulted in the same error.

I have tried without the dynamic domain and putting one of the real LoadUriBase values in and **that worked just fine:**

`<LoadUri>https://anactualwebsite.co.uk/{OAUTH-KV:LoadUriResource}.html</LoadUri>`

Also works without the `.html` but doesn't work without the `/` after the `.co.uk`, and of course I need the LoadUriBase to be present, this just confirms that it's that part causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

To any soul looking for an answer to this question in the future, I have found a simple workaround to B2C not supporting this that's a little easier than setting up a proxy server.

If you, like me, had 5 different TrustFrameworkExtension files all identical except for the LoadUri and each referenced by a different Signin file, you can specify just the desired LoadURI in the Signin file. Your TrustFrameworkExtension file will look like this:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ContentDefintions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="your.content.definition.id">
      <!-- Insert all data except the LoadURI here -->
    </ContentDefintion>
    <!-- Insert any other ContentDefintions here -->
  </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Then add this to your Signin file:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ContentDefintions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="your.content.definition.id"> <!--Importantly must be the same ID used in the TrustFrameworkExtenson! -->
      <LoadURI><!-- Insert LoadURI value here --></LoadURI>
    </ContentDefintion>
  </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

This will extend the ContentDefinition with ID `your.content.definition.id` defined in the TrustFrameworkExtension file to include the LoadURI specified.